# How to select where LIKE char() or hex()

Tags: sql, sqlite

I ultimately want to remove parts of string that contain the latin character 'à', so my idea was something in the like of these:

```
select * from table where column like '%hex(E0)'
select * from table where column like '%char(E0)'
```

I tried these too:

```
'%' + char(133)
'%' + hex(E0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latin character `'à'` has ascii code `224` (hex E0). 
You can replace it say with `'a'` in a column like this:

```
select replace(columnname, char(224), 'a') from tablename
```

or update the table

```
update tablename
set columnname = replace(columnname, char(224), 'a')
where columnname like '%' || char(224) || '%'
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. It turns out not all ascii tables on the internet are reliable. The one I had found stated that 133 was the right char number... I was also rusty on the concatenation..

Comment: ASCII only defines characters up to 127.  After that the extended code represents depends on the code page you're using.